# Suppose $\frac{a_n}{b_n} $ converges to a limit S. Show that $\frac{\sum_{n=0}^{N}{a_n} }{\sum_{n=0}^{N}{b_n} } $ converges to that same limit S

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, ratio

I'm having a little trouble solving this problem :

Consider two sequences of real numbers,  $\ (a_n)_{n \ge 0}$, and $\ (b_n)_{n \ge 0}$, with  every $\ b_n >0 $, such that $\frac{a_n}{b_n}  $  converges to a finite limit S.

Show that  $\frac{\sum_{n=0}^{N}{a_n}  }{\sum_{n=0}^{N}{b_n}  } $ converges to that same limit S, when N approaches $ +\infty$.

The way I'm approaching this problem is by reasoning with the epsilon definition of a limit :

Consider $ \epsilon >0 $. There exists $ N_{0}\in \mathbb N $ such that, for every $ n\ge N_{0}$ : $ \left| \frac{a_n}{b_n} -S \right|  \le \epsilon $

In that case, I would think it useful to write :

For every $ N\ge N_{0}$ : $ \left| \frac{\sum_{n=0}^{N}{a_n}  }{\sum_{n=0}^{N}{b_n} } -S \right|  =  \left| \frac{\sum_{n=0}^{N}{a_n}  }{\sum_{n=0}^{N}{b_n} } -\frac{a_N}{b_N} + \frac{a_N}{b_N} -S \right| \le \left| \frac{\sum_{n=0}^{N}{a_n}  }{\sum_{n=0}^{N}{b_n} } -\frac{a_N}{b_N} \right|+\left| \frac{a_N}{b_N}-S \right| \le \epsilon+ \left| \frac{\sum_{n=0}^{N}{a_n}  }{\sum_{n=0}^{N}{b_n} } -\frac{a_N}{b_N} \right| $

Another useful strategy might be to find lower and upper bounds of $\frac{\sum_{n=0}^{N}{a_n}  }{\sum_{n=0}^{N}{b_n}  } $  that both converge to .

Unfortunately, I've hit a roadblock on both these methods, and don't really see how to go forward.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This must be a duplicate, I think. Someone might find it for you. But maybe some condition is missing, such as $\sum b_n = \infty$.

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem).

Comment: You have to assume that the $b_n$ have all the same sign.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Yes that's right, as mentioned, the sequence $\ (b_n)_{n \ge 0}$, is chosen such that every $\ b_n >0 $

Comment: If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n < \infty$ then there are counter-examples.

Answer (score 1):

It's wrong as stated. Take $a_n=\frac{1}{n^2\log n}$ and $b_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$. Then $\frac{a_n}{b_n} = \frac{1}{\log n} \to 0$ but $\frac{\sum_{n=1}^N a_n}{\sum_{n=1}^N b_n} \to_{N \to \infty} c \neq 0$.